# Unix Processes PIPE

Tags: c, unix, process

I have the following assignment to do :

Ping-pong. Two processes will play the ping-pong game.
    The first process will generate a random number between 5000 and 15000  that will be send to the other process.
    This process will subtract a random value (between 50 and 1000) and will send the number back,
    The chat between the processes will be implemented using pipe channels.
    The game ends when the value is below zero.
    Each process will print the received value.

So i wrote the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int p[2];
    int a, n;

    pipe(p);
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        int r = 0;
        srand(time(NULL));
        while ( r < 50 || r > 1000)
        {
            r = rand();
        }

        if ((a=read(p[0], &n, sizeof(int)))==-1)
            perror("Error read pipe:");

        printf("Process 2 recived %d\n", a);
        a = a - r;

        close(p[0]); close(p[1]);
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        while ( n < 5000 || n > 15000) {
            n = rand();
        }

        while (n > 0)
        {
            printf("Process 1 recived %d\n", n);
            if (write(p[1], &n, sizeof(int))==-1) 
                perror("Error write pipe:");

            wait(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When it is executed it goes in a infinite loop which prints `"Process 1 received 4"` and i don't know why.

I created another pipe and now it prints correctly the first received value but from the second process it happens the same thing

```
Process 1 recived 9083
Process 2 recived 4
Process 1 recived 4
and infinite loop
```

Comment: Please do not update code in your question.

Comment: Note that the two sequences of random numbers are virtually guaranteed to be the same (they'll only be different if one of the processes happens to execute `time(NULL)` at time T and the other at time T+1, but mostly they'll both execute it at time T).  A simple fix is to use `time(NULL) + pid` in place of `time(NULL)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you a corrected program with the explanation in comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int p[2];
    int p2[2];
    int a, n;

    pipe(p);
    pipe(p2);
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(p[1]); // not writing in p, so closing p[1] immediately
        close(p2[0]); // not reading in p2, so closing p2[0] immediately

        srand(time(NULL));

        do {
            if ((a = read(p[0], &n, sizeof(int)))==-1)
                perror("Error read pipe:");

            if (a == 0) // nothing read means all processes have closed p[1]
                n = 0;
            else
                printf("Process 2 recived %d\n", n);

            int r = 50 + rand() % 950; // Only need one random number, and need one different each time
            n -= r;
            if (n > 0)
            {
                if(write(p2[1], &n, sizeof(int))==-1)
                    perror("Error write pipe:");
            }
        } while (n > 0);

        close(p[0]); close(p2[1]);
        exit(0); // or return(0) - as pointed out by Stian
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        close(p[0]); // not reading in p, so closing p[0] immediately
        close(p2[1]); // not writing in p2, so closing p2[1] immediately

        srand(time(NULL) + pid); // Adding pid so that processes each use a different seed
        n = rand() % 10000 + 5000; // Only need one random number

        while (n > 0)
        {
            if (write(p[1], &n, sizeof(int))==-1) 
                perror("Error write pipe:");

            // wait(0); Wrong use of wait()
            if ((a = read(p2[0], &n, sizeof(int)))==-1)
                perror("Error read pipe:");

            if (a == 0) // nothing read means all processes have closed p2[1]
                n = 0;
            else
                printf("Process 1 recived %d\n", n);

            int r = 50 + rand() % 950;
            n -= r;
        }

        close(p[1]); close(p2[0]);
    }

    wait(NULL); // Better use of wait(). Still not perfect, you need to check return value.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Child should call _exit when finished, else it will reach wait

Comment: @StianSkjelstad: And since the child has no children of its own, the `wait()` will return `-1` and `errno == EAGAIN` immediately, which isn't a problem except that a (harmless) system call was made that could have been avoided.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed, not an error, just an unnecessary call, and I don't like them...

Comment: You code substract the random value from n in the father procces, why ?

Comment: @gamamen2 That's what I understood in your assignment, but of course if you don't agree with me don't do it. What is important is you to understand how to use the two pipes so the processes can communicate. Adapt my answer as you think it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You need two pipes. One for each direction

Comment: like a pipe for the child and a pipe for the father ?

Comment: A pipe is a one direction data stream. One pipe should be written by parent and read by the child, and the second pipe the reverse

Comment: I made another pipe and i still get a infinite loop, can you look over the edit ?